I want to add a pop up on a page load in a Volusion based site
I have a Volusion based site and a Klaviyo code. I don't know where to add the code or how to add it so it pops up during the page load.
Here is the code:
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('.klaviyo_form_trigger').addEventListener('click', function (){
        window._klOnsite = window._klOnsite || []; 
        window._klOnsite.push(['openForm', 'WZ8DUD']);
    });
</script>


I've tried adding it above the  tag but that did not seem to work. I do not code so I really do not know what I am doing or how to edit it.
